# Django model form validate using attributes of fields

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

Model,

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(A)
    y = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Model form,

```
class ABCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ABC
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can I validate this model form using attributes of x and y.

I don't want to use plain django form or clean methods.

Can I do it something like ?

```
ABCForm(data={'x__some_attr': 123, 'y__some_attr': 431})
```

Comment: Why close vote ?

Comment: For the very reason voters gave when voting to close your question: no one understand what you're asking.